# Cannot get image file at server side from File Uploader in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, htmlcontrols

I have html control as `fileuploader`and i add `runat="server"` to it to access it at server side, I don't want to user `asp:FileUploader` because of its bad `css` style especially in `bootstrap`

```
<span>
<input type="file" runat="server" id="File_Upload" />
</span>
```

Now i need to get image from this html `fileUploder` to save it in `database` I got example code from google to get image from `fileuploader` as

```
Byte[] imgbyte = null;
if (File_Upload.PostedFile != null)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = File_Upload.PostedFile;
    imgbyte = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, file.ContentLength);
 }
```

but when i examine by using `breakpoint` then compiler does not enter into `IF` body because of `Null` vaule

I also used this

```
 ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(this.File_Upload);
```

in `Form_Load` Event due to using `asp:UpdatePanel`

but i didn't get file (Image) from `FileUploader`

I need your help to solve this issue..

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

When i remove `asp:UpdatePanel` then i can access file that i select.

and also use

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="File_Upload" />
   </Triggers>
```

**Solution:**

Mistakenly i used FileUploader's ID and by following @Suprabhat's suggestion i change it as

```
<Triggers>
              <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreate" />
           </Triggers>
```

and now working fine..

Comment: So, you have added **PostBackTrigger** but **ControlID** should include the name of button which is sending a post message not the name of  file upload control id that is selecting a file.

Comment: Oh.... sorry i didn't notice that.. thanks for your time ... now its working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `form` element.

Comment: i checked this... it didn't worked due to update panel